# How can I use both css and sass files in angular 7?

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have the following mix of `Material` and `bootswatch` which cause a compiler error:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
@import "~bootswatch/dist/yeti/_variables.scss";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import "~bootswatch/dist/yeti/_bootswatch.scss";
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

The error is:

```
    ERROR in ./src/styles.css (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(1:4) Unknown word

> 1 | // Yeti 4.3.1
    |    ^
  2 | // Bootswatch
  3 |
```

According to [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-with-the-angular-cli), I can use `ng set defaults.styleExt scss` to start processing Sass files.

> However, it doesn't go through the process of converting your already existing .css files to .scss files. You'll have to make the conversion manually.

Can keep my `css` files and import what I need of `sass` files, side by side?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can just import the sass files into your project. If you are doing a `sass -watch` and outputting it to a normal css file, then just import your compiled css file.

Comment: If my answer does not help could you let us know what error is shown when trying to import the stylesheets?

Comment: @designtocode how does `sass -watch` work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to support SASS in your application, consider only replacing the extension of your `css` files with `.sass` which will work without any further modification. This is because SASS is a superset of CSS and therefore simple CSS will be fully compatible.

---

Edit: Would the imported CSS not be of your own but rather from an external package (such as a node module), then removing the `.css` extension from your import should fix the problem:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink';
@import "~bootswatch/dist/yeti/_variables.scss";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import "~bootswatch/dist/yeti/_bootswatch.scss";
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

Comment: Is that replace works for angular material files? because in that case I should execute `ng set defaults.styleExt scss` and start replacing all of my files I guess,  how can I be sure not to leave any one?..

Comment: @TiyebM in this case I would not recommend the first solution as your changes will be overriden when reinstalling the external package. Let me know whether the second solution works for you.